# selecting row matching condition, and also one row above and one row below

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, slice

I am trying to select rows in a Dataframe which meet a condition, and also the rows just before it and just after it(even if those rows do not meet the condition.)

The condition is that the value in df['col1'] is less than 100

```
idx=df.index[df['col1']<100]
```

`df.loc[idx]` gives me all the rows matching the condition df['col1']<100

To also get one row above and one row below, I have tried to slice using `df.iloc[idx-1:idx+1]` but i get the error message

> TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class
> 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'> with these indexers
> [Int64Index([ 23362,  23363,  23364,  23365,  23366,  23367,  23368,
> 23369,
> 23370,  23371,
> ...
> 129089, 129154, 129155, 129156, 129157, 129158, 129159, 129160,
> 129161, 129162],
> dtype='int64', length=7851)] of <class 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the bool so do not need to filter it by `index` , we can do `shift` for the mask

```
m = df['col1']<100
df = df[m.shift(-1)|m.shift()|m]
```

Comment: Oh wow, yes. This worked. (I used `~` because I actually want to remove the rows meeting the condition)   `df=df.loc[~(mask.shift(-1)|mask.shift(+1)|mask)]`

By the way, what is your recommendation on when to use mask and when to use the index and loc?